# com.viewpagerindicator android.view.view

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to use JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator in a project.
http://viewpagerindicator.com/

I unzipped JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator and started a new project in this folder.
In the file UnderlinePageIndicator.java I have an error on:

```
import android.view.View;
...
public class UnderlinePageIndicator extends View implements PageIndicator { ... }
```

Error: *View can not be resolved to a type.*
I also have an error on line 1 (which is a comment), saying:
*The type android.view.ViewGroup cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files*

Error Log:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for android.view.ViewGroup. Fix the build path then try building this project  JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator-8cd549f      Unknown Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type android.view.ViewGroup cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  UnderlinePageIndicator.java /JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator-8cd549f/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator  line 1  Java Problem
```

I spent hours on this, im out of solutions. Any help would be welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: post your error log.

Comment: and with your error log, please add more code... two lines without the one with the error is a little bit too much for us to help you

Comment: i dont know what code i could add... The rest of it is fine. It's just that i can't access the View class from android.view, while it is correctly imported. I guess its a problem of project setup, as this project is supposed to be a kind of library that you use in your own code; it does not have a main application and you can't compile it on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **import** `JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator` into ur workspace and then **right click** on your `project->properties->android->library(scroll_down)->Add button` dialog will open,then select `JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator` and click  **apply/ok**.
2. And then follow this link "[Adapter for circle page indicator in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104861/adapter-for-circle-page-indicator-in-android/26045735#26045735)". I have used CirclePageIndicator with viewpager.It will absolutely help u :)

Comment: I got it. I was just importing it the wrong way (using Import "Existing Project into Workspace" instead of "Existing Android code into Workspace").

Comment: thx your answer solved my problem but i don't have the 15 reputation points to vote you up ;)

Comment: okies dear. Its my pleasure u have got ur answer.So plz UPVOTE my answer it will help  of others. :)

Comment: Still you can follow my profile n we will keep in touch